# Capture json tree structure at the type level

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I'm in the process of implementing the [Fibre](https://docs.odriverobotics.com/protocol.html) protocol. The way the protocol works is that you recieve a json object which represents the operations and values you can do on a remote object. Below is an example of such a json.

```
{
  "name": "properties",
  "type": "object",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 1,
      "type": "uint32",
      "access": "rw"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "id": 2,
      "type": "uint32[]",
      "access": "r"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "type": "object",
      "members": [
        {
          "name": "baz",
          "id": 3,
          "type": "float",
          "access": "rw"
        },
        {
          "name": "some_function",
          "id": 4,
          "type": "function",
          "inputs": [
            {
              "name": "param1",
              "id": 5,
              "type": "float",
              "access": "rw"
            },
            {
              "name": "param2",
              "id": 6,
              "type": "bool",
              "access": "rw"
            }
          ],
          "outputs": [
            {
              "name": "result",
              "id": 7,
              "type": "bool",
              "access": "rw"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As can be seen it's essentially a tree with properties and functions of certain types. Some properties can only be read which is indicated by access being `r` and some can be read/written indicated by access being `rw`. Capturing this structure in Haskell is straightforward with some data definition:

```
data FibreType
   = FibreInt8  | FibreUInt8
   | FibreInt16 | FibreUInt16
   | FibreInt32 | FibreUInt32
   | FibreInt64 | FibreUInt64
   | FibreFloat
   | FibreBool
   | FibreJSON
   | FibreList FibreType
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data FibreAccess = FibreReadable | FibreReadWriteable
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data FibreObject
   = FibreValue
       { _fibreValueName     :: String
       , _fibreValueEndpoint :: Word16
       , _fibreValueType     :: FibreType
       , _fibreValueAccess   :: FibreAccess
       }
   | FibreFunction
       { _fibreFunctionName     :: String
       , _fibreFunctionEndpoint :: Word16
       , _fibreFunctionArgs     :: [FibreType]
       , _fibreFunctionResult   :: [FibreType]
       }
   | FibreObject
       { _fibreObjectName    :: String
       , _fibreObjectMembers :: [FibreObject]
       }
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

getProperty :: FibreObject -> IO ByteString
getProperty FibreObject{} = error "Cannot get property of FibreObject"
getProperty FibreFunction{} = error "Cannot get property of FibreFunction"
getProperty FibreValue{} = undefined -- Implementation removed for brevity

setProperty :: FibreObject -> ByteString -> IO ByteString
setProperty FibreObject{} = error "Cannot set property of FibreObject"
setProperty FibreFunction{} = error "Cannot set property of FibreFunction"
setProperty FibreValue{_fibreValueAccess = FibreReadWriteable} = undefined -- Implementation removed for brevit
setProperty FibreValue{} = error "Cannot set property of read-only FibreValue" 

callFunction :: FibreObject -> [ByteString] -> IO [ByteString]
callFunction FibreObject{} _ = error "Cannot call function for FibreObject"
callFunction FibreValue{} _ = error "Cannot call function for FibreObject"
callFunction FibreFunction{} args = undefined -- Implementation removed for brevit
```

But I really don't like that once I make the function `getProperty` or `callFunction` I lose all type safety and I essentially have to hack around this by making all inputs and outputs `ByteString`(or I could define a sum type) and then later deserialize to certain concrete values. So I wonder if it's possible to lift this structure to the type level even though that json definition is only available at runtime.

The goal is that I would be able to write something like this:

```
getProperty :: FibreValue type access -> IO type
getProperty FibreValue{} = undefined -- Implementation removed for brevity

setProperty :: FibreValue type FibreReadWriteable -> IO () 
setProperty FibreValue{} = undefined

callFunction :: FibreFunction [argTys] [resTys] -> argTys -> IO [resTys]
callFunction FibreValueFunction args = undefined -- Implementation removed for brevity
```

This would give full type safety without having to match on a result type which really could only be a single value. I release there are problems with the function definition I have given for `callFunction` but it's more to illustrate the point.

Is this possible in Haskell? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217195/discussion-on-question-by-john-smith-capture-json-tree-structure-at-the-type-lev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible API design is

```
data SFibreAccess :: FibreAccess -> Type where
    SFibreReadable :: SFibreAccess FibreReadable 
    SFibreReadWriteable :: SFibreAccess FibreReadWriteable
-- contructors (and record fields) should be hidden
data FibreValue s a
   = FibreValue
       { fibreValueName     :: String
       , fibreValueEndpoint :: Word16
       , fibreValueType     :: FibreType
       , fibreValueAccess   :: SFibreAccess a
       }
data FibreFunction s
   = FibreFunction
       { fibreFunctionName     :: String
       , fibreFunctionEndpoint :: Word16
       , fibreFunctionArgs     :: [FibreType]
       , fibreFunctionResult   :: [FibreType]
       }
data FibreObject s
   = FibreObject
       { fibreObjectName    :: String
       , fibreObjectMembers :: [FibreSpec s]
       }
data FibreSpec s
   = forall a. FibreSpecValue (FibreValue s a)
   | FibreSpecFunction (FibreFunction s)
   | FibreSpecObject (FibreObject s)

data FibreAPI s
   = FibreAPI
       { fibreAPISpec :: FibreSpec s
       , fibreAPIGet :: FibreValue s a -> IO ByteString
       , fibreAPISet :: FibreValue s FibreReadWriteable -> ByteString -> IO ByteString
       , fibreAPICall :: FibreFunction s -> [ByteString] -> IO [ByteString] -- further type safety for function calls possible but tedious and not done here
       }

-- internal
data SomeFibreSpec = forall s. SomeFibreSpec (FibreSpec s)
getAndParseFibreSpec :: URL -> IO SomeFibreSpec
-- exposed
withFibreAPI :: URL -> (forall s. FibreAPI s -> r) -> IO r
withFibreAPI url cont = do
    SomeFibreSpec spec <- getAndParseFibreSpec url
    return $ cont FibreAPI
        { fibreAPISpec = spec
        , fibreAPIGet = \_ -> throwIO $ userError "unimplemented"
        , fibreAPISet = \_ -> throwIO $ userError "unimplemented"
        , fibreAPICall = \_ -> throwIO $ userError "unimplemented"
        }
```

The phantom parameter to `FibreSpec` means that, under a call/within the continuation to `withFibreAPI`, the arguments to the get, set, and call functions are guaranteed to come from taking the `fibreAPISpec` object apart. (The constructors and record fields are untouchable, and mixing `FibreAPI`s from different calls to `withFibreAPI` is a type error.) This prevents creating a `FibreValue` or `FibreFunction` out of the blue and expecting the functions to work. `FibreValue`s also come tagged with their access control. Checking whether the property passed to `fibreAPISet` is accessible still needs to be done by *someone* (you would do it by getting the `fibreValueAccess` and `case`ing it), but now, once you check it once (and gain evidence `a ~ FibreReadWriteable`) every call will let you through, instead of repeatedly giving you a `Maybe` or whatever.

EDIT: Making the functions type safe:

```
data SFibreType :: FibreType -> Type where
    SFibreInt8 :: SFibreType FibreInt8
    -- etc.
    -- if it isn't obvious
    SFibreList :: SFibreType a -> SFibreType (FibreList a)
-- other names: HList, Product, HMapList, etc.
-- SList is really only correct for the combined type SList s where s is a singleton family, but whatever
data SList :: (a -> Type) -> [a] -> Type where
    SNil :: SList s '[]
    SCons :: s x -> SList s xs -> SList s (x : xs)
-- replace FibreFunction, FibreSpec
data FibreFunction s args ress
   = FibreFunction
   { fibreFunctionName     :: String
   , fibreFunctionEndpoint :: Word16
   , fibreFunctionArgs     :: SList SFibreType args
   , fibreFunctionResult   :: SList SFibreType ress
   }
data FibreSpec s =
   = forall a. FibreSpecValue (FibreValue s a)
   | forall args ress. FibreSpecFunction (FibreFunction s args res)
   | FibreSpecObject (FibreObject s)

data family ValueOf (t :: FibreType) :: Type
newtype instance ValueOf FibreInt8 = MkInt8 { getInt8 :: Int8 }
-- etc.

-- modify FibreAPI
data FibreAPI s
   = FibreAPI
       { fibreAPISpec :: FibreSpec s
       , fibreAPIGet :: FibreValue s a -> IO ByteString
       , fibreAPISet :: FibreValue s FibreReadWriteable -> ByteString -> IO ByteString
       , fibreAPICall ::
            forall args ress.
            FibreFunction s args ress ->
            SList ValueOf argss ->
            IO (SList ValueOf ress)
       }
```

Getting type safety for properties is similar: put the `FibreType` into the arguments of the specification part type, put an `SFibreType` into the actual values in place of the `FibreType`, put existentials in `FibreSpec` and put universals in `FibreAPI`.

Comment: So I guess it's not possible what I want. You have solved half the problem with the access rights. But not the problem with the the arguments/return values(They are still `ByteString`) of the fibre functions. If it's not possible to gain evidence of `fibreValueAccess` via the data structure itself it seems kind of useless to do this as the case just get's moved around.

Comment: The cases have to go *somewhere*. The only thing types can give you is "memory": once you check them once (by `case`ing on `fibreValueAccess`) you don't have to do them again. You can't eliminate them because that would imply you *know* which properties are readable and writable before you even asked the server for the specification. But then, why'd you even ask for it? Making the functions type-safe is easy enough, but it's tedious and I thought it was similar enough to what's already here that it could be figured out. I've realized it's actually not similar, so my bad. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Thank you this is much clearer now. The only thing I haven't gotten to work is the `FibreList`.  I had to change `newtype instance` to `data instance` in the `ValueOf` data family. But I don't know/understand how I can get `FibreList` to work with that...

`data instance ValueOf (FibreList t) = [ValueOf t]` can't be parsed.

Comment: Oh, oops. `data instance`s are basically their own data types, and should have constructors. `newtype instance ValueOf (FibreList t) = MkFibreList { getFibreList :: [ValueOf t] }` and similarly for the other types. Editing...

Comment: Thank you for being so patient! It now works exactly as I envisioned! I was able to eliminate the `s` phantom type parameter. Not sure what the purpose was.

Comment: To prevent you from creating `FibreSpec`s that don't correspond to anything read from the server. Removing it breaks everything. Now you're able to do `main = void $ withFibreAPI url \(FibreAPI _ set _) -> set (FibreValue "bar" 2 (FibreList FibreInt8) SFibreReadWriteable) empty` or similar to modify `bar`, which is meant to be read-only. Or: use a `FibreSpec` from a different URL, which doesn't even use the hidden constructors: `main = do { FibreSpecValue v <- withFibreAPI url1 \(FibreAPI s _ _ _) -> return s; withFibreAPI url2 \(FibreAPI _ get _ _) -> get s }`

Comment: Is this not  easily fixable by not exposing the constructors? You are right that a different Fibre device could be used with a wrong FibreSpec though.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, that's why my answer says to hide the constructors (and the record fields, as they can also mutate). However, safety is only achieved when both hidden constructors *and* phantom types are used. (Note: you can't "hide" `FibreSpecValue` or `FibreAPI`, which are the only constructors used in my "no-constructors exploit". Even if you hide them, you need to *somehow* get the `FibreValue`s out of a `FibreSpec` etc. in order for the API to be usable, and "decomposition" is all you need to break it without phantoms.)